# Two ways to generalize: If $k[a,b,c] \subsetneq k[x]$, then there exist $f,g \in k[x]$ such that $k[a,b,c] \subsetneq k[f,g] \subsetneq k[x]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, for example $k=\mathbb{C}$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428075/do-there-exist-polynomials-f-g-such-that-mathbbca-b-c-le-mathbbcf-g?rq=1) question asked if for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$, there exist $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that
$\mathbb{C}[a,b,c] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[f,g] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$.
The answer was positive.

Now I wonder if this result can be generalized to at least one of the following claims:

- **First generalization:**
  For $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, there exist $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that
  $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[f,g] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
- **Second generalization:**
  For $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, there exist $f,g,h\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that
  $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[f,g,h] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

There are other palusible variants, but for now the above two variants suffice.

I am more interested in the first generalization and wonder if the proof of the one-dimensional case can be directly generalized to the two-dimensional case with just replacing $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{C}[y]$; I guess this would not be enough.

**Remarks:**

1. I wonder if in the original question one cound have considered only $a,b \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ without $c$ or equivalently with $c \in \mathbb{C}$.
2. Here for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ maybe one would have to consider $f,g,h \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
3. I am not sure yet what is the role of algebraic (in)dependence in those questions.

Thank you very much!